# CTabView class: Is it possibile to put tabs on top?

Tags: tabs, mfc

I was wondering if it is possible to have the tabs in the top position rather than the bottom. I know that `CTabView` encapsulates a `CMFCTabCtrl`, but I cannot see how I can set the tabs position.

Answer (score 4):

[CTabView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983705.aspx) encapsulates a tab control ([CMFCTabCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984302.aspx)). It is exposed through the [CTabView::GetTabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983539.aspx) member. The [CMFCTabCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984302.aspx) derives from [CMFCBaseTabCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983503.aspx). The latter implements a [CMFCBaseTabCtrl::SetLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc702178.aspx) member, that allows to set the tab area position. The position can be either `LOCATION_BOTTOM` or `LOCATION_TOP` as documented under [CMFCBaseTabCtrl::GetLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982434.aspx).

To set the tab area position to the top for a `CTabView` instance use the following code:

```
MyTabView.GetTabControl().SetLocation( LOCATION_TOP );
```

Comment: @vinnythepoo: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)